# Excel persistent evaluate if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to evaluate an expression only if a certain condition is met. The reason I am doing this is to allow the user to "lock" a value so that changes to other variables in the formula have no effect anymore.
I tried using the function below which works great until I close the sheet and open it again.
I already tried to use an additional cell passed as parameter to copy the value to it when it's not locked and copy it back if so however excel does not allow other cell modifications within a function.
Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

```vb
Function EvaluateIf(expression As String, condition As Boolean) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim myText As String
    Dim myVal As Variant
    If condition Then
        myVal = Application.Evaluate(expression)
    Else
        myText = Application.Caller.Text
        If IsNumeric(myText) Then
            myVal = Val(myText)
        Else
            myVal = myText
        End If
    End If
    EvaluateIf = myVal
End Function
```

**EDIT1:**
I need to apply this function onto multiple cells so I cannot hard code the cells

**EDIT2:**
I currently call the function like this in excel:
`=EvaluateIf(N$7*IF(ISBLANK(P$7);1;P$7)*IF(ISBLANK(R$7);1;R$7);NOT(V$7))`

Comment: A function in one cell can't modify another cell, that's when you use VBA to do it instead. So you can have sub run as you open the sheet, to collect the stored value from the additional cell.

Comment: But how do I store the value in first place? I also need to apply the function to multiple cells to hard coding is not an option

Comment: Please, show us how do you call the function. How does that 'condition' look?

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to store the value somewhere in a sheet. No variables will be kept. As for how to do it; either just store it in some cell that you know won't be used, as backup, reading it when the document is opened. If that's not an option, you could have a sub trigger as you close the document, saving the value on a new sheet, which is then read and removed upon opening the document.

Comment: @FaneDuru I added an example function call. My condition is something like `NOT(A1)'

Comment: @ChristoferWeber I'd be fine with adding a parameter with the backup cell to the function, however I don't know how to write it to the backup cell inside my function as, as far as I know, this is not possible

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were using it as a UDF in the sheet. I guess you would have to have an autimatically triggered macro to fetch the variable from the cell then. But then I guess the problem is finding them all, so looping through the used cells, looking for the `EvaluateIf` formula, recording the value and position... which seems like a bit of work.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Thanks for your reply. I am also open for different approaches if there are any

Comment: A worksheet_change event which tracks the `V7` cells (if that's feasible) might be a place to start.  How exactly is the user to trigger the "lock" of a value?

Comment: @TimWilliams The 'lock' is just a simple checkbox or a cell which is one or zero. As each function as its own 'lock', how do I know which lock belogs to which cell?

Comment: You use `Application.Evaluate(expression)` but expression has *already* been evaluated by Excel before it calls your UDF: do you need the evaluate for some specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out - normal cautions apply to using this method to skirt around the restrictions applied to the use of UDF when called from a worksheet.

```vb
Function EvaluateIf(expression, condition As Boolean, backup As Range) As Variant
    Dim myText As String
    Dim myVal As Variant
    Dim bak
    
    bak = backup.Value
    If condition Then
        myVal = expression
        If myVal <> bak Then 'update cached value?
            Application.Evaluate "SetBackup(""" & backup.Parent.Name & """,""" & _
                                            backup.Address & """,""" & myVal & """)"
        End If
    Else
        myVal = bak
    End If
    EvaluateIf = myVal
End Function

Sub SetBackup(ws As String, addr As String, v)
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'avoid infinite loop!
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws).Range(addr).Value = v
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```